# I have three images to be cross faded in the splash screen in React native. How can I do that? Kindly help me

Tags: react-native, splash-screen

I used react-native-splash-screen library. I did animations in the splash activity . But it shows only the last image without any animations and load into my mainscreen.

Comment: I think if you want to add animation. You should add a splash screen view and open it 1st, and you add animation when you navigate to another screen.

Answer (score 0):

Splashscreens can only have still images, so if you need to accomplish the animation you need to put a still image (preferrably the first frame of your animation) in the splashscreen and then first thing the app renders is the animated splashscreen which is a normal screen with the animation you want that continues the splashscreen. It has a timer so when the animation finishes you just move to your app